# Angular 6 EventEmitter doesn' t work

Tags: angular, angular6, eventemitter

**this is the service**
    **the service implements two EventEmitter**

```
 @Injectable()
    export class SpinnerService implements HttpInterceptor {
        visibility: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter(false);
        notVisibility: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter(false);
        constructor() { }
        intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            **doesn 't work**
            this.visibility.emit(true);
            next.handle(request).subscribe(
                httpParameter => {
                    if (httpParameter instanceof HttpResponse) {
                        this.notVisibility.emit(false);
                    }
                });
            return next.handle(request);
        }
    }
```

**this is the component**

```
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit {
    visibility: boolean;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.subscribeToVisibility();
        this.subscribeToNotVisibility();
    }
    constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) { }

    private subscribeToVisibility(): void {
        this.spinnerService.visibility.subscribe((value: boolean) => {
            **should enter here**
            this.visibility = value;
        });
    }
    private subscribeToNotVisibility(): void {
        this.spinnerService.notVisibility.subscribe((value: boolean) => {
            this.visibility = value;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry fot the code, please look at the service,

Comment: 1. `EventEmitter`s are specifically for component `@Output`s, just use a regular `Subject` here. 2. What does *"doesn't work"* mean, exactly? Are you sure you're getting the same service instance in both cases (see e.g. my blog https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Jul/15/angular-http-client.html where I show how to use the same instance as both an interceptor and an injected service)?

Comment: sorry I'm a beginner with angular, every service does not have a single instance?in the example passed by my boss does not use @Output, in any case I tried it and it does not work. How can I know if it is the same instance?

Comment: I'm not saying you should add `@Output`, I'm saying you should move away from the `EventEmitter`. And no, every service doesn't necessarily have a single instance; if your class appears twice in the module `providers` array you need to be careful to ensure it's actually the same instance. Read that article, see the example at the end.

Comment: Change the `EventEmitter`s to `Subject`s (and change the `.emit(...)` call to `.next(...)`). What exactly "doesn't work"?

Comment: after emit from the service it does not come in here: this.spinnerService.visibility.subscribe ((value: boolean) => {
             ** should enter here **
             this.visibility = value;
         });

Answer (score 0):

I think is much better to separate SpinnerService from interceptor and create interceptor service , usually in your case the interceptor service is not calling as you mentioned ,check my implementation of spinner based on interceptor service.

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interceptor-spinner)

*interceptor service*

```
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private spinner: SpinnerService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.spinner.visibility.emit(true);
    return next.handle(req)
      .pipe(
      delay(1000), // delay is not required just to observe the effect
      finalize(() => this.spinner.notVisibility.emit(false))
      )
  }

}
```

*spinner service*

```
export class SpinnerService {

  public visibility: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();
  public notVisibility: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

}
```

add the services to AppModule providers array

*app.module*

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
     { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: InterceptorService, multi: true },
    , SpinnerService
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

*component*

```
export class AppComponent {

  public visibility: boolean = false;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient, private spinnerService: SpinnerService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.spinnerService.visibility.subscribe(state => {
      this.visibility = state;
      console.log('visibility', state);
    });

    this.spinnerService.notVisibility.subscribe(state => {
      this.visibility = state;
      console.log('notVisibility', state);
    });

  }

  getData() { // make http request 
    this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .subscribe(console.log)
  }
}
```

*template*

```
<button (click)="getData()" [disabled]="visibility">Get Data!</button>

<div>
    visibility {{visibility}}
</div>
```